# Double to string with max one digit after dot

Tags: c#, .net, string.format

How do I format a Double to String:

```
1715 --> 1.7K
500 --> 0.5k
```

Comment: Yes, i have try ToString("0.#"), ToString("#.#")

Comment: @user3328870, as a tip, you should include those attempts when you ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read for example about [Numeric Format String](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), then use with proper value:

```
double value = 1715.0;
string result = (value / 1000.0).ToString("F1", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture) + "K";
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do it like this:

```
 Console.WriteLine("{0:0.0}K", 1715/1000d);
```

Here is the [`fiddle`](http://dotnetfiddle.net/W3W1Lf)

**Further reading**

- [The "0" Custom Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx#Specifier0)